# Here a word is a string of letters, preceded and followed by nonletters

Tags: regex, unix

I asked his question earlier but none of the responses solved the problem. Here is the full question:

Give a single UNIX pipeline that will create a file file1 containing all the words in file2, one word per line.Here a word is a string of letters, preceded and followed by nonletters.

I tried every single example that was given below, but i get "syntax error"s when using them.

Does anyone know how I can solve this??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if your regex flavor support it you can use lookarounds:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]+(?![a-zA-Z])
```

`(?<!..)`: not preceded by
`(?!..)`: not followed by

If it is not the case you can use capturing groups and negated character classes:

```
(^|[^a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]+)($|[^a-zA-Z])
```

where the result is in group 2

`^|[^a-zA-Z]`: start of the string or a non letter characters (all character except letters)

`$`: end of the string

or the same with one capturing group and two non capturing groups:

```
(?:^|[^a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]+)(?:$|[^a-zA-Z])
```

(result in group 1)

Comment: Hmm... the middle example seems to make sense. I'll reply later if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: The first one didn't work. The second one gave me the error "syntax error near unexpected token `^'

Comment: @Casimir... None of these option are working. I keep getting syntax errors. I'm suing Opensuse... Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When your objective is to actually find words, the most natural way would be

```
\b[A-Za-z]+\b
```

However, this assumes normal word boundaries, like whitespaces, certain punctuations or terminal positions. Your requirement suggests you want to count things like the "example" in "1example2".
In that case, I would suggest using

```
[A-Za-z]+
```

Note that you don't actually need to look for what precedes or follows the alphabets. This already captures all alphabets and only alphabets. The greedy requirement (+) ensures that nothing is left out from a capture.

Lookarounds etc should not be necessary because what you want to capture and what you want to exclude are exact inverses of each other.

#### [Edit: Given the new information in comments]

The methods below are similar to Casimir's, except that we exclude words at terminals (which we were explicitly trying to capture, because of your original description).

**Lookarounds**

```
(?<=[^A-Za-z])[A-Za-z]+(?=[^A-Za-z])
```

Test [here](http://regexr.com?382l0). Note that this uses negated positive lookarounds, and not Negative lookarounds as they would end up matching at the string terminals (which are, to the regex engine as much as to me, non-alphabets).

If lookarounds don't work for you, you'd need **capturing groups**.
Search as below, then take the first captured group.

```
[^A-Za-z]([A-Za-z]+)[^A-Za-z]
```

When talking about regex, you need to be extremely specific and accurate in your requirements.

Comment: thanks, AnkurTG. The problem with your suggestion is that I would fine all letters when I only want to find letters that are surrounded by non-letters. So if a file had these lines:

Comment: donkey                                                               -03??/donkey2342342

Comment: then your suggestion would fine both donkeys, but I would only want the second one

Comment: You have a very strange definition for a word. I would consider a whitespace or a string termination as also a "non-letter". You should have phrased it as "surrounded by characters which are not alphabets".

Comment: I have expanded my answer - the new ones will exclude terminal words. Hope it works in the regex system you use.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be unicode compatible, you could use:

```
(?:^|\PL)\pL+(?:\PL|$)
```

`\pL` stands for any letter in any language
`\PL` is the opposite of `\pL`